With a Canada tourist visa, can Philippines passport holders visit South Korea for 7 days visa-free?
Can my family visit South Korea with a Canada multiple-entry visa on a Philippines passport?

Yes, providing you meet the following conditions:

Visa Exemptions:


Nationals of Philippines with an entry visa issued by Australia, Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 30 days.


They must:

arrive from the country that issued the visa and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 30 days; or
arrive from a third country and have a confirmed onward ticket for a flight within 30 days to the country that issued the visa.



The entry visa must be in the form of visa sticker on the passport, except for Australian visas. If passengers have a transit point before arriving in Korea (Rep.) or after leaving Korea (Rep.), the maximum stay in that transit country must be within 3 days.


Passengers traveling as tourist to Jeju (CJU) are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 30 days. They must hold confirmed tickets and other documents for their next destination.


Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card valid for travel to "KOR" for a maximum stay of 90 days.

Source: Timatic

It's important to note that this applies to people in transit between the country which issued the visa and another country. So they can do Philippines -> Korea -> Canada or Canada -> Korea -> Philippines for instance, but they cannot do Philippines -> Korea -> Philippines or Canada -> Korea -> Canada.

@jcaron As I read it, they cannot arrive direct from the Philippines either. So Philippines>Korea>Canada doesn’t work. Correct me if I’m wrong, I’ll edit my answer to make the TWOV exemption 100% clear.

what makes you think that? It's clearly designed for transit, so as long as you are on your way to or from the country the visa is for (and logically, in the vast majority of cases, the other end of the journey will be the traveller's home country) one should be OK. "Third country" here means at least "not Korea", probably "not Korea nor the country that issued the visa", but it could be any other country, including the traveller's home/residence country.

@jcaron Ok, I interpreted ‘third country’ as meaning not Philippines.

one would have to check the official text, but IMHO it wouldn't make much sense.

Unfortunately, a Canada multiple-entry visa doesn't grant entry to South Korea. Your family will need to apply for a South Korean visa using their Philippines passports. Be sure to check the latest visa requirements from the South Korean consulate before planning your trip. Safe travels!

Actually, as shown in Traveller's answer, it can, but only in the specific case of transit on their way between Canada and another country.
